# Why is the Angular filter running twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So here is some simple sample code I setup from an example today while I was learning Angular.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/W5vJS/)

Couple questions:

1. How does it know to run `categoryFilterFn`. I'm guessing anything binded to the html view and the `$scope` is somehow just executed "in case" there are changes.
2. Why does the filter run twice? If you run the example you will see eight console statements for the four products. Even if I move it all into one controller it still does this.

Comment: I'm guessing that filters run for every digest. And your code happens to produce 2 digests? Maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does it know to run categoryFilterFn. I'm guessing anything binded
>   to the html view and the $scope is somehow just executed "in case"
>   there are changes.

Yes the Angular digest cycle does dirty checking to see if anything has changed.  It does this over the watch queue (and things are put in the watch queue based on if they are bound in the UI).

> Why does the filter run twice? If you run the example you will see
>   eight console statements for the four products. Even if I move it all
>   into one controller it still does this.

Again, Angular uses dirty checking ([here is a good article about it](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/)).  Essentially, during the start of a digest cycle the watched value is resolved.  Then, at the end of the digest cycle, the value is resolved again (this is the second call).  If the values do not match, the UI is replaced with the new values.  In very simple terms, this is how the two-way binding works.

Comment: Well to 1. that's what confuses me, because I'm not actually changing anything. It just set's a local variable in the `prdouctList` controller.  It's not changing the data in anyway. It seems to just run every method attached to `$.scope` that is also used in the view somewhere. Or what you're trying to say is that the whole thing sort of reloads each time you interact with the page?

Comment: You should check out that article I referenced.  Every change that causes a digest, checks _everything_ and then rebinds anything that is affected.

Comment: Ok, well that makes more sense now.

Comment: I guess the next question is, are there any optimizations for this?

Comment: Yes, you can use [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) if you don't want to watch.  I would expect some help from the core angular on this in upcoming versions as well.